# How to protect the code of Windows applications against path traversal?

Tags: path-injection

I'm writing a simple HTTP server in Lua and while I can easily find resources on how to secure against Unix directory traversal, I already found some caveats in the Windows version. While I'm already looking for `C:\` at the beginning (C being "any letter" here), `../` and `/..` (with backslash as the directory delimiter as well) and `\\` at the beginning. The code will be passed to ANSI C `fopen()`, compiled under Microsoft Visual C++ v10 (no idea what's the system call this call compiles to). Are there any other traps I should look out for in this case?

I'm only interested in solutions involving the modification of my code, most preferably by checking the filename against patterns.

Comment: I *really* hope this is just a project for the sake of learning.

Comment: It is. Here's the code: https://svn.nmap.org/nmap/ncat/scripts/httpd.lua

Comment: Ah, you mean the HTTP server I wrote? More of a demo, with a big warning "don't use it on production". Yet I'd rather make it secure. Its main use scenario is simple file (or directory) sharing over a trusted network.

Answer (score 7):

Paths in Windows are [relatively complex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In particular, Microsoft has a habit of inventing new features, so even if your HTTP server is really protected against path traversal *today*, it may become vulnerable under next version of Windows, possibly even a small update.

Right now, your are using "blacklist-thinking": you are trying to enumerate all the "bad" constructions, and specifically detect them. Blacklists are known to be fragile because it is very hard to be exhaustive, and then to *remain* exhaustive. **You should use whitelist-thinking**, i.e. define a syntax for *allowed paths* and exclude everything else.

For instance, define that an allowed path consists in a sequence of *components* separated by slash characters ("/", not "\"), with the following rules:

- A component contains only letters, digits, dashes ("-"), underscores ("_") or dots (".").
- A dot may not appear as first or last character in a component.
- There shall not be any two consecutive dots in a component.
- A component contains at least one character, and at most 64 characters (arbitrary limit).
- No two consecutive slashes may appear in a path.
- A path does not begin with a slash.
- A path is not empty.
- The total length of a path shall not exceed 250 characters.

All these rules are easy to enforce programmatically. And they guarantee a "clean local path" that you can send to `fopen()`. Note that most Windows functions are perfectly happy with the "/" as separator, but you may still want to replace all slashes by backslashes (*after* checking all the rules above, of course).

Comment: Is 'component' just the word you are using for a directory? Because it is valid (but perhaps misguided) for a filename to be `test......txt`, for example, which would violate the two-dot rule.

Comment: Yes, I am using "component" as meaning "directory or file". The point is that, for a HTTP server, I don't actually need to support every possible path name; I just have to support paths which "make sense". I can declare that `test......txt` will not be allowed, even if the underlying Windows would have accepted it. (Similarly, IIS, the HTTP server from Microsoft, will reject file names which contain a "+", even though Windows itself has no problem whatsoever with such names -- and rejecting names with a "+" is very rarely an issue.)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I can see your point now.