# What bytes are stripped by info-zip?

Tags: appsec, directory-traversal

I see many software that check only for`..`between path separators. For a long time I thought they were no possibility to exploit invalid bytes *(for example attempt to create`.‌.`will lead to`.?.`on osx)*.

But I saw cve‑2003‑0282 yesterday. So what are the invalid characters that can trigger that bug on vulnerable versions.

I tried to search more about this, but it sees [all the relevant links on the cve report are dead](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2003-0282).

Comment: [related](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/121511/36301)

Comment: http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/7550/info has more information about this CVE including an exploit.

Comment: http://www.info-zip.org/FAQ.html#corruption links to https://lwn.net/Articles/38540/ which calls them "non-printable characters". From the example at the link from @SteffenUllrich's, `0x03` does the trick.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara : ok but I don’t understand why : in other archivers, the file would simply  be created with those characters *(except if the filesystem doesn’t support it)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the patch](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/cdimage/snapshot/Debian/pool/main/u/unzip/unzip_5.50-1woody2.diff.gz) it can be seen that it is skipping any control and some more characters (`[\x00-\x1f\x7f\xff]`) when constructing the target file name:

```
+        * SECURITY: Skip past control characters if the user
+        * didn't OK use of absolute pathnames. lhh - this is
+        * a very quick, ugly, inefficient fix; it traverses
+        * the WHOLE path, eating up these as it comes to it.
+        */
+       dp = cp;
+       do {
+           workch = (uch)(*dp);
                 ...
+            } else if (workch == '.' && !snarf_ddot) {
+               snarf_ddot = TRUE;
+           } else if (isprint(workch) ||
+                      ((workch > 127) && (workch <= 254))) {
+               /*
+                * Since we found a printable, non-ctrl char,
+                * we can stop looking for '../', the amount
+                * in ../!
+                */
+               break;
+           }
+
+           dp++;
+        } while (*dp != 0);
```

Comment: Good, I was unable to find the patch. However, it stills doesn’t resolve the problem : in other archivers the file containing those character would simply be created.

Comment: @user2284570: which problem you describe? This patch removes special characters when extracting the files from the archive so that it does not matter if some other archiving program created a malicious archive.

Comment: : normally if create a file ᴀꜱᴄɪɪ control characters with it’s name, the filename will contains them. I can’t see how see how they could have been stripped when attempting to create`..`.

Comment: @user2284570: sorry, but I'm unable to understand your problem. It might help if you explain it in more depth and also add more context.

Comment: repeating it differently : normally if your create a file ᴀꜱᴄɪɪ control characters with it’s name, the filename will contains them. So what should happen is a new directory is created instead of`..`being recognized and leading to path traversal.

Comment: @user2284570: still not clear what your problem is. Maybe we have a different understanding what the code is doing: it is simply ignoring control characters when looking for directory traversal pattern, i.e. `..` and `.\x03.` will be treated the same and traversal attempt is detected.

Comment: Yes, what I do not understand is why such bytes are ignored *(or rather than why they were ignored on vulnerable versions)*.

Comment: @user2284570: I still don't understand your problem. Please try to describe it in more than a short phrase. Your question makes probably sense in your current mindset but I don't know this mindset so you need to go back and explain the context of your question deep enough so that I and maybe others can understand it.